# Paste code from Python into Word (Macbook)

Tags: python, ms-word, insert

I want to paste the code I wrote in Python into a Word document. I have a Macbook. I don't want the code to lose its formatting (indentations and colors).
I have already tried it via Insert/Text/Object and with the programs Sublime Text and Atom, unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) can copy text with code highlighting, but I don't recommend it. In this case, I think it's best to just post a screenshot to your Word document.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with screenshots is that one line of code is sometimes very long and gets cut off when you take a screenshot.

Comment: @Julia Try VS Code, it will do the job. Tho I won't recommend it either, but if you have your reasons then you can go for it.